# Application wide logging in MVC 4 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-logging

What is the best method for implementing application wide logging in MVC4 ? Is it possible to implement a global exception logging using configuration only ?
Is there any existing practice to assign some sort of custom levels to it ? (e.g.: trace, warning, error, exception etc)

Comment: [Log4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net) should be ample.

Comment: Is it possible to configure Log4net to have an application wide logging ? I am trying to implement some logging mechanism to log all unhanded exceptions and application errors.

Comment: @smehnawal - you can simply implement your own HandleErrorAttribute and then register it in the global filters.  In your attribute, you log the eception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is pretty popular for unhandled exception logging, but it can be a bit challenging to get working correctly in MVC.

I personally use [Elfar](http://sourceforge.net/p/elfar/wiki/Home/) which is "inspired" by Elmah but is more targeted at MVC.

There are various ways to incorporate regular logging into your app, lots of them in fact.  [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), and others give you tools to do logging.

Comment: I haven't personally used Elfar, but it looks promising. Nonetheless, I have used Elmah and there is an _MVC_ flavour to it called [Elmah.MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah.mvc), which is fine in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexR. - Yes, there is an MVC version, but it's still way more complicated to setup than it should be.  I find Elfar to be a lot simpler to get working.